# Add Columns And Separate By Category

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I have a datatable that is using standard features (pagination, sorting, searching, date range, etc.), but I also need to have a portion at the bottom of the table that displays the total salary of each office.  The output would (ideally) look something like this if you searched for, say, "engineer":

- London: $295,500
- San Francisco: $409,350
- Singapore: $234,500
- Tokyo: $139,575
- Edinburgh: $103,600
- New York: $125,250
- Total Hours: $1,307,775.00

I have tried a handful of different approaches, but frankly my script knowledge is lacking and I am out of my depth.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this issue?

Here is my script:

```
"footerCallback": function (row, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api(),
                    data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function (i) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
                };


                // ************NOT WORKING************ \\   
                // Total by category

                // First Attempt 
                if (api.column(5,
                    {
                    search: 'applied'
                    })
                    .data()
                    .length) {
                    var byCategory = api
                        .rows()
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, c) {
                            a[c[7]] = a[c[7]] || 0;
                            a[c[7]] += intVal(c[5]);
                            return a;
                        },
                        {});
                }
                else {
                    byCategory = 0;
                }
                console.clear();
                console.dir('by category', byCategory); 
                /*
                // Second Attempt
                if (api.column(5, {
                    search: 'applied'
                }).data().length) {
                    var byCategory = api
                        .rows(5, {
                            search: 'applied'
                        })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (category, hours) {
                            category[hours[7]] = category[hours[7]] || 0;
                            category[hours[7]] += intVal(hours[5]);
                            return category;
                        }, {});
                }
                else {
                    byCategory = 0;
                }
                console.clear();
                console.dir('by category', byCategory); */
                // ************NOT WORKING************ \\  

                // Third Attempt
                /*var byCategory = api
                    .rows()
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, c) {
                    a[c[7]] = a[c[7]] || 0;
                    a[c[7]] += intVal(c[5]);

                        for (var key in byCategory) {
                            if (byCategory.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                console.log(key + " -> " + byCategory[key]);
                            }
                        }                    
                }, {}); */

                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(5)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Total over all filtered pages
                if (api.column(5, {
                    search: 'applied'
                }).data().length) {
                    pageTotal = api
                        .column(5, {
                            search: 'applied'
                        })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        });
                } else {
                    pageTotal = 0;
                }                 

                // Update footer
                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(                    
                    pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' hours ( ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total hours)' + '<br>' + Object.entries(byCategory) + ' hours'
                    //pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' hours ( ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total hours)' + '<br>' + Object.keys(byCategory).map(key => { console.log(key, byCategory[key]) }) + ' hours'
                    //pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' hours ( ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total hours)' + '<br>' + Object.keys(byCategory).forEach(key => { console.log(key, byCategory[key]) }) + ' hours' 
                );
            }
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/l337method/hfyo90w7/

Comment: Hi @l337method, i'm not sure how you display that. but [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31038/how-to-sum-column-based-on-values-from-another-column) will help you to understand

Comment: Oh, awesome.  I had not found that example while I was scavenging for information.  Thank you. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can do sum of salary by office using below code sample as said over [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31038/how-to-sum-column-based-on-values-from-another-column), which you can modify according to your need. 

Replace `1` by column number you want to compare data with.

```
 total = api.cells( function ( index, data, node ) {
                        return api.row( index ).data()[1] === 'textA' ?
                            true : false;
                    }, 0 )
              .data()
              .reduce( function (a, b) {
                  return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
              } );
```

To be more specific : you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/6qLwkwud/189/), you can use this function to sum up values. see @davidkonrad for exactly what you want with filter.

```
$("#example").on('search.dt', function() {
    alert(table.column( 0, {page:'current'} ).data().sum() );
});
```

Comment: I am trying to find how to have it iterate through and display the sums for each category instead of just matching "X" category and displaying the sum.  This does appear to be the first step though.  I'll see what I can come up with...

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to minimize the results of the total to display only the filtered total, would you?  I am struggling with the syntax.

Comment: I'm not getting what are you saying.

Comment: So, for instance, if I was to sort my jsfiddle by "accountant" it gives a filtered total as well as the overall total.  The way that the code is set up in these couple examples that you showed me it just displays the overall total for the office.  The way I got around this before was with the line:
.column(5, { search: 'applied' })

I am not sure how to implement this with .cells, however.

Comment: Ah, ha!  I figured it out.  The syntax for .cells is just a hair different.  Ended up needed to write it like: .cells({ search: 'applied'},function(index, data, node) 

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider using the small [**`sum()`**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()) plug-in. In your case, all what you need next is something like

```
drawCallback: function() {
  var sum = this.api().column( 5, { search:'applied', page: 'all' }).data().sum();
  $( this.api().column(5).footer() ).text(
    '$'+Number(sum.toFixed(1)).toLocaleString()
  );
}
```

You can translate this into "*get the sum of all column(5) values from all pages, but only those which is not filtered out*". `drawCallback` will be triggered each and every time you search, filter etc.

Here is a forked version of your fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/7cjL35dr/**

The code was a little bit confusing so I tried to cleanup before I added the `sum()` plugin and the `drawCallback`.

Comment: Sorry, that is just my inexperience poking through. I'll try and clean up the code a bit using your suggestions.  Thanks!